# Some of JavaScript functions not working on Chrome browser, why?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have develop one JavaScript function for hiding and showing my textbox. This functionality works fine in Mozilla but not in Chrome browser. I don't know why. My function:

```
function selectType()
{   if(document.getElementById("promotype").value=="Amount")
    {   document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("type").value = 'amount';
    }
    if(document.getElementById("promotype").value=="Percentage")
    {   document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("type").value = 'percentage';
    }

    if(document.getElementById("promotype").value=="Freesignup")
    {   document.getElementById("amount").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "block";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("promotype").value=="Gift cards")
    {   document.getElementById("amount").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("selectmemberdiv").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {   if(document.getElementById("promotype").value=="Freeride")
        {   document.getElementById("amount").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("type").value = 'none';
            document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "none";
        }
        else
           document.getElementById("amount").style.display = "block";    
        document.getElementById("selectmemberdiv").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

First when my page is load at that time I will hide my 'amount' textbox after when I click on drop down at that time based on category to show my amount textbox.

But why they are not working in Chrome browser?

Comment: Yes but that function no any error.

Comment: means its workin in chrome??

Comment: not working in chrome?

Comment: that's bracket that we only found mistake in your code

Comment: have you alert any this in your function in chrome??

Comment: Besides all that, i would recommend you to turn this huge `if/else` into `switch` statement and comparing the values in lower case. Moreover, you are creating lot of duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

Add `bracket` in last `else` condition

```
<script>
    function selectType()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("promotype").value == "Amount")
        {
            document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("type").value = 'amount';
        }
        if (document.getElementById("promotype").value == "Percentage")
        {
            document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("type").value = 'percentage';
        }

        if (document.getElementById("promotype").value == "Freesignup")
        {
            document.getElementById("amount").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "block";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("promotype").value == "Gift cards")
        {
            document.getElementById("amount").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("selectmemberdiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            if (document.getElementById("promotype").value == "Freeride")
            {
                document.getElementById("amount").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("type").value = 'none';
                document.getElementById("typediv").style.display = "none";
            }
            else
            {// this bracket
                document.getElementById("amount").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("selectmemberdiv").style.display = "none";
            }// end else condition
        }
    }

</script>
```